# Unable to resize the thumbnail in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, resize, thumbnails

Here is my code:

```
$imgdata = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($id, 'thumbnail' );
$imgurl = $imgdata[0]; 
$imgwidth = $imgdata[1]; 
$imgheight = $imgdata[2];
if( !empty($imgurl) ){
    echo '<img src="'.$imgurl.'" width="10" height="1" alt="" />';  
}
```

The image size is always 365x228.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regenerate Thumbnails plugin** is by far the easiest solution for managing anything related to thumbnail dimensions.

[Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)